# Can't start ethernet network connection

Tags: networking, connection, ethernet

After electric surge grub loader has stoped working which i fixed with 'grub-install', but now i can't make ethernet working again. Bootable version of Ubuntu doesn't working too. What is the lowest-level eth0 recovery steps there is that i could apply to my problem?

ifconfig:

```
eth0
  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:04:4b:c4:bd  
  inet6 addr: fe80::23d:9ff:fe4b:c4bd/64 Scope:Link        
  UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1  
  RX packets:302 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0   
  TX packets:343 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0      
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000        
  RX bytes:20208 (20.2 KB)  TX bytes:74524 (74.5 KB)         
  Interrupt:16

lo
  Link enc ap:Local Loopback      
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0        
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host         
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1         
  RX packets:756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0        
  TX packets:756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0         
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0        
  RX bytes:87621 (87.6 KB)  TX bytes:87621 (87.6 KB)
```

Comment: it seems the system sees the ethernet interface, but you cant connect to the internet? Have you tried `dhclient eth0`

Comment: RTNETLINK answer: Operation not permitted

Comment: try running it as root `sudo dhclient eth0`

Comment: sudo dhclient eth0 
worked for me!